# Jquery popover and asp.net button

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using a jQuery popover and an asp.net button inside of it. The button click is not firing. I added $(this).parent().appendTo("form"); to the open function but it still isnt firing.

Script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

$('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover({
    html: true,
    title: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();

    },
    content: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();

    },

    open: function () {

        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
    }


});
//]]>
```

Markup

```
  <div class="popover-markup"> 
<a href="#" class="trigger"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-2x" title="Save Grid Layout" style="color:#108ec6; padding:5px;"></i></a> 
<div class="head hide">Save Report</div>
<div class="content hide">
    <div class="form-group">

      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtReportName"  CssClass="form-control" Width="150px" placeholder="Report Name" />
    </div>
    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block" ID="btnSaveLayout" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSaveLayout_Click"/>

</div>
```

Comment: I got it submitting but I am not getting the value of the textbox. I added "UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="popover" to the button and it now fires.

Comment: have you done this? is there any solution to get the value of the textbox. please post